# How do you prevent the tests from stopping on the first failed test case?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, assertion

I'm attempting to check if certain pieces of content are present, on different pages. For example:

```
const contentCount = Selector('.some-element').childElementCount

.expect(contentCount).gte(1, 'The related content is missing.')
```

... Which works fine, except that the testing stops after the first assertion fails. This isn't ideal as I'm trying to generate a report that shows ALL of the failed assertions at once.

How do I get the test to keep running after a failed assertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question from the subject first (how to prevent the test from stopping on the first **failed test case**).

TestCafe will run all tests even if one of them failed. You might want to split your single test case with multiple assertions into multiple test cases with a single assertion per test to obtain a proper report.

Now, answering your question from the body (how to keep running after a **failed assertion**).

At the moment, there is no way to skip a failed assertion during the test execution. TestCafe considers that something went wrong if an assertion failed, so the entire test fails. However, if you don't want an assertion to fail a test, you may add a condition for it; e.g.:

```
if (contentCount > 0)
  await t.expect(contentCount).gte(1, 'The related content is missing.')
```

But, this does not look like straight and predictable test logic. So, I would choose splitting a test into multiple tests with one assertion per test.

See also: [TestCafe Assertions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/assert.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Without getting into too much detail about our setup, keeping multiple assertions within a single test would be ideal.

I'm not sure if this has already been requested - but It'd be nice if we could opt into continuing the (same) test even if an assertion fails. An additional option on runner.run() perhaps?

Comment: For me, the main purpose of any test is to check that some functionality works properly. However, if something breaks, this means that this functionality does not work completely. I would prefer the test to fail in this case.

Imagine that your car has a V6 engine, but 1 of 6 spark plugs does not work. This is an issue that must be fixed, and I would prefer that my spark plug checking test fails if at least one spark plug malfunctioned.

Comment: As an alternative, you may create single assertion in a test for all conditions at once and provide a complete actual result. In this case, you may see the difference between expected and actual results.

Comment: Makes sense. Perhaps my test case scopes are too broad in nature then, and should be narrowed down to be more granular. Thanks for the help, and keep up the great work! TestCafe is an amazing tool.