# Output all failures instead of one in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

How can i display all failures when running tests.

```
test('test case', async (t) => ){
   await t.expect(1).eql(2);
   await t.expect(3).eql(4);
}
```

What i get (first failure, then stops):

> 1) AssertionError: expected '1' to deeply equal '2'

What i want (all wrong data):

> 1) AssertionError: expected '1' to deeply equal '2'
>
> 1) AssertionError: expected '3' to deeply equal '4'

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614503/how-do-you-prevent-the-tests-from-stopping-on-the-first-failed-test-case

In short answer you have to split your single test to multiple tests to see all the fails in one run

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is a bit more complicated than that. I've created a function where 400+ objects are iterated trough and checked if correct. This is not efficient to put in 400 test cases. 

I hope the reporter plugin has some workarounds that someone has discovered to export this data.

Comment: Only option I can think of is not using testcafe assertion, but making your own, for example: 
    if (1 != 2) console.log('Failed');
    if (3 != 4) console.log('Failed');

Comment: That is actually not a bad idea! I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome, this works. Thanks for the tip Stiks ;)

```
let x = 0;

for (let i in result1){
    if (result1[i] != result2[i]){
        x += 1;
        console.log( x +') AssertionError: expected ' + result1[i] + ' to deeply equal ' + result2[i] );
    }
}
await t.expect(x).eql(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work, just put all elements in array and iterate trough them

```
for(let i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
    test
    (`Test `+i, async t => {
        await t.expect(i).eql(i+1);
    });
}
```